# Event handling to toggle visibility of a sibling SVG element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to toggle the visibility of the sibling of a mouse event target.

I have an "event box component" comprised of an `SVG` `group` containing a `circle`, a `rect` and a `text` element. The functionality I need is that a click on the red circle (shown in the image below) toggles the visibility of the yellow rect. I have a click event attached to the `circle` and can toggle its "state" but I don't know how to access its sibling, the `rect`.

This is probably pretty simple but I'm not finding any good examples. I don't want to broadcast a general event (if I don't have to) as there will be multiple "event box components". I guess I can pass some "id" so it is only handled by the appropriate `rect`(?).

Is there a standard `d3` way of handling this sort of thing? I'm coming from an obkect-oriented Actionscript background where accessing a parent and siblings is fairly simple.

Extra question... am I handling the visual "state" correctly in the code below? I am adding and removing classes for each "state" for the red circle. It works but seems a bit clunky. Is there a more standard way to do this?

---

[image]

---

```
     function eventClick(d, i) {
        if (d3.event.altKey == false) {
            if (d.state == false) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .classed("event-box", false)
                    .classed("event-box-hilite", true);
                d.state = true;
            } else {
                d3.select(this)
                    .classed("event-box", true)
                    .classed("event-box-hilite", false);
                d.state = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d3.select(this.parentNode)
  .select('.event-box')
```